# How to pass value into directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have button in my html which has a directive on it. I would like to pass a value to that directive:

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button" minimize-popup mdMenu="$mdMenu">
```

In my directive I have:

```
return {
    scope: {
        mdMenu: '='
    },
    link (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.mdMenu);
```

But the log shows the line as undefined. I guess it's because the the `minimize-popup` and the `mdMenu=$mdMenu` have no relation to each other.

Comment: in your html, try `md-menu="$mdMenu"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your parameter name has to be normalized to `md-menu` otherwise angularjs will normalize it to `mdmenu` which will never match `mdMenu` within the directive definition.

Second, make sure `$mdMenu` is defined on your scope; because angularjs will look for a variable in scope since you made the bind like `mdMenu: '='`.

Bellow there is a simple snippet with a directive with parameter for you to use as an example.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      scope: {
        'myParam': '='
      },
      link(scope, elem, attrs){
        console.log(scope.myParam)
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="test = 'foo'">
  <div my-directive my-param="test"></div>
</div>
```